# Spring tool suite pom.xml Project build error (Non-resolvable parent POM)

Tags: xml, maven, spring-boot

I just made my first Spring Starter Project and I keep getting this error.

> Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:AOP_demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:2.1.3.RELEASE from/to repository.spring.milestone (https://repo.spring.io/milestone): sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM

I didn't change anything in my POM.xml file.

I already tried deleting the .m2 file and updating Maven. I am trying this on my work laptop but everything works fine in my personal laptop. I believe this is happening because some network problem. Can anyone help me diagnose this further?

EDIT:
entire POM=

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>                              
  <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.19.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>AOP_demo-3</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>AOP_demo-3</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<repositories>
<repository>
    <id>central-repo</id>
    <name>Central Repository</name>
    <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
</repository>
</repositories>



<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: It could be because you are behind a firefall

Comment: I'm not sure. Can't seem to find anything. At the moment, I'm trying to make a certificate to fix the PKIX path building failed. Is this the right way?

Comment: can you please share the complete pom?

Comment: I added it in an edit

Comment: There seems to be no isssues in pom. Tried it locally. Can you try connecting your office laptop to different network to confirm if it is firewall issue

Comment: So I added this code into my POM: <repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central-repo</id>
        <name>Central Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

Comment: Now it says that it can't find my dependencies. I also added this code into the POM.xml file above if that's easier to read.

Comment: Not required. Did you try connecting to different network from your office laptop?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but I solved it.

Try to change the spring version `1.3.1.RELEASE`. Then run maven (with `mvn clean install` or what I did: `mvn package`) and it starts downloading all the artifacts/dependencies.

After this you could change the version back to `1.5.19.RELEASE` and the dependencies are valid.

It looks like maven stops searching in other repositories when it couldn't found the parent spring 1.5.19 version.

After this, I deleted the repositories-block from the pom file, but it still works